# Eager-Loading Assets in Matrix

Tags: templating, matrix, eager-loading, assets-field

I've been using [this example](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements#eager-loading-elements-related-to-matrix-blocks) to eager load images, stored in an Assets field which is located in a Matrix field.

My query looks like this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('project')
.with(['projectMatrix.imageBlock:imageFile']) %}
```

Where `projectMatrix` is a Matrix field, `imageBlock` is a Matrix block type and `imageFile` is an Asset field inside `imageBlock`.

But how do I reference the that image in my templates?

```
{% for entry in entries %}

{% set matrixImage = entry.projectMatrix.type('imageBlock')[0].imageFile[0] ?? null %}

...

{% endfor %}
```

This is always be `null`, when eager loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because `.type('image')` won't work with eager loading. Eager loading removes the ability to use `ElementCriteriaModel` methods.

From the docs:

> When the assets aren’t eager-loaded, entry.assetsField gives you an ElementCriteriaModel that is preconfigured to return the related assets once they’re requested (e.g. when first() is called).
>
> However when the assets are eager-loaded, entry.assetsField gets overwritten with an array of the eager-loaded assets. So first(), find(), and other ElementCriteriaModel methods are not available. Instead you must stick to the standard array syntaxes.

As a work around, you could use a for loop to match only Matrix blocks of a particular type instead:

```
{% for block in entry.projectMatrix if block.type == 'imageBlock' %}
  {% set matrixImage = block.imageFile[0] %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you only want the first image block type:

```
{% for block in entry.projectMatrix if block.type == 'imageBlock' %}
  {% if loop.index == 1 %}
    {% set matrixImage = block.imageFile[0] %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah! It makes sense, thank you for explaining :)